# Heavy computation in background task in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance

I am fairly new to stackoverflow, have tried to explain as much as I could, any help is appreciated, really struggling with the following.

I am performing heavy computation (data download) as follows:

```
    public static String fetchhttp_2(String urlstring) {

    String value = null;
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlstring);
        BasicHeader d = new BasicHeader("X-Zomato-API-Key", CommonLib.APIKEY);
        httpPost.addHeader(d);
        BasicHeader d2 = new BasicHeader("Authorization", "Basic emRldjoxTjRDMlFBOVUyNUNrcDE=");
        httpPost.addHeader(d2);

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token", prefs.getString("access_token", "")));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", CommonLib.CLIENT_ID));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));

        HttpResponse response = HttpManager.execute(httpPost);
        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream in = entity.getContent();
            value = convertStreamToString(in).toString();
            return value;

        } else {
            CommonLib.ZLog("responsecode", urlstring + " --- " + responseCode);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        CommonLib.ZLog("Error fetching http url", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return value;
}
```

This works in most cases, other than the ones, where the response gives me heavy data.

I have tried following:

**Call this from Async task.**

```
private class MyClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    ArrayList<myList> restaurants = null;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... p) {
        String url = "http://myUrl.com";
        myObj =  // get data from url using snippet above
    }
```

in my oncreate:

```
new GetRestaurantCompact().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
```

**Start this in a thread:**

```
Runnable r  = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
// same code the goes in async task
}
Thread th = new Thread(r);
th.start();
```

**Start this code in a service**

```
Intent i= new Intent(context, MyService.class);
context.startService(i);
```

Helper function
`

```
public static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    try {
        return new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError ex) {
        CommonLib.ZLog("splash", "Out of memory exception while download");
        return "";
    }
}`
```

I tried putting the service code in Async as well as a separate thread.
**The problem is, the task holds up UI thread, and makes the UI non responsive, until it gets over.**

**None has helped really**

Comment: But what is the problem?

Comment: Ah too much into issue, edited it now. The thread computation is blocking the UI, and making the app really slow

Comment: The service shouldn't work because it runs on the UI thread (unless you create a thread inside the service). Other methods should would, no matter how cpu intensive your code is. There must be something else.

Comment: I have tried to create  a thread inside service, that didn't work either. I am doing all of this under onCreate, this shouldn't be a problem right ?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I have edited the code, and put the helper funcrtion, to read the large string, if that can go crazy, in smaller phones(Samsung S3, which aint that bad!), this did go OutOFMemory. I generally otherwise work on Nexus 4

Comment: Also, Post downloading the string, which essentially is an XML, I parse it, which has around 10K entries. The complete data is about 3MB.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49449/discussion-between-ankit-and-merlevede)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the priority of the thread:

```
Thread th = new Thread(runnable);
th.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
th.start();
```